# Convert a while loop to for loop in pseudo code

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop

I need to convert this loop to a for loop.

```
Input:A number k ≥ 0 
Output: Output ?? 
x←0
y←0
while x≤k do 
x←x+1 
y←y+3
return y
```

Also can you describe me the output of this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't describe what language you were thinking of, and I didn't recognize the syntax of your while example. But this C code should be a for-loop equivalent of that code.

```
for(x=0, y=0; x <= k; x++) y += 3;
```

Of course, if you only care about the result, this could be replaced by

```
y = 3*(k+1);
```

Edit: Ok, so as pseudo-code, this could be something like

```
y←0
for each x from 0 to k inclusive do
    y←y+3
end do
return y
```

But I find the proper C code much clearer, myself.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i've wrote i need it in pseudo code.

Comment: Pseudo-code isn't one single thing, though. I am not familiar with the pseudo-code syntax you are using, but I will edit my answer with some passable pseudo-code doing what you want.

Comment: yes i also understand it in C better, but i need this one in pseudo code. Thank you again.